# How to use elements of list of Lists in the same formula in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I need to use elements from the list of lists in the same formula

```
import math

def equate(A):
    n = len[A]
    sum = 0
    for i in A:
        sum = sum + ((A[i] * math.log10(A[j]) + (1-A[i] * math.log10(1 - A[j]))
    loss = -1/n * sum
    return loss

A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
Answer = equate(A)
print(Answer)
```

Getting below Error

```
File "/home/988659d072a77d5e9b58fa933c5d006f.py", line 7

loss = -1/n * sum
   ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You forgot two closing brackets on the `sum = sum + ...  `line

Comment: Also, don't use  `sum`. Sum is a reserverd word in python!

Comment: @kabooya - `sum` isn't reserved but your point remains valid - never use `sum` as an identifier (unless you are monkey-patching the built-in `sum` function).

Comment: ```j``` is not defined, did you mean ```i```?

Comment: also, what exactly are you trying to do? It isn't quite clear..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis.

```
sum = sum + ((A[i] * math.log10(A[j]) + (1-A[i] * math.log10(1 - A[j]))) 
# Missing a parenthesis at the end.
```

Comment: I think if you only edit the parentheses, the code will contain other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import math

def equate(lst:list):
    n = len(lst)
    suma = 0
    for i, j in lst:
        suma = suma + ((i * math.log10(j)) + (1-i * math.log10(1 - j)))
    loss = -1/n * suma
    return loss

A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
answer = equate(A)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want, although it's hard to say because `A`, `i` and `j` are really non-informative variable names

```
from math import log10
from statistics import mean

def equate_one(i, j):
    return i * log10(j) + (1 - i) * log(1 - j)

def equate(A):
    return -mean(equate_one(i, j) for i, j in A)

A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
Answer = equate(A)
print(Answer)
```

- I think you mismatched the parenthesis: `1 - i * something` is the same as `1 - (i * something)`.
- `len[A]` would try to index `len` rather than get the length of `A`.
- `sum` is a builtin function, which you shouldn't override.
- `i` is in your code a two-element list, so you cannot do `A[i]`
- As pointed out by a121, `j` was not defined.
- You missed not one, but two closing parentheses on the line before the syntax error. Over-using parentheses (can ((easily (lead)) (to confusion))).
- Use the standard library! If you want the arithmetic mean of a certain set of numbers, use the `statistics` library that comes with Python.